# PLEASE: Behat trouble with selenium and chrome extensions

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, behat

Hi I have been working on this for 2 days now and i really need some help here. I have referred to many answers here but not getting a solution. I have been trying to setup behat with selenium and chrome extensions for my tests. But failing to do so. any help will be very much appreciated. thank you. The error on my feature file is as follows:

```
@javascript
  Scenario: Test the add group functionality invalid number of parent groups # features/groups.feature:28
    Given I am on homepage                                                   # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
      Could not open connection: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
      Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
      System info: host: 'Digitals-iMac.local', ip: '10.18.1.204', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '11.0.1'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
    When I will login as globaladmin                                         # FeatureContext::iWillLoginAsGlobaladmin()
    Then I should see "groups"                                               # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    Then I click "Groups"                                                    # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    Then I click "Add group"                                                 # FeatureContext::assertClick()
    When I fill in "edit-label-0-value" with "Group1"                        # FeatureContext::fillField()
    When I fill in "edit-groups-target-id" with "Echidnet, Group1"           # FeatureContext::fillField()
    Then I press "Create group and become a member"                          # FeatureContext::pressButton()
    Then I should see "Error message"                                        # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()

--- Failed scenarios:

    features/groups.feature:4
    features/groups.feature:16
    features/groups.feature:28
```

This is my behat.yml file

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      path: %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
      contexts: 
        - FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://somesite.com/
      javascript_session: chrome
      selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://somesite.com/"
        browser: chromedriver
        capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", "version": "65", 'chrome': {'switches':['--no-sandbox', '--headless']}}
      browser_name: chrome
      sessions:
        default:
          goutte: ~
        chrome:
          selenium2:
            browser: chrome
```

this is the selenium standalone prompt to my executions (it says browser is firefox when i am trying to use chrome. i am not sure how to fix that or where i have even mentioned it to use firefox):

```
09:43:27.074 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
09:43:27.089 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browser": "firefox",
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "ignoreZoomSetting": false,
  "name": "Behat feature suite",
  "tags": [
    "Digitals-iMac.local",
    "PHP 7.2.15"
  ]
}
```

Any other file such as my feature or feature context file also i can provide but i did not think it was required. I am stuck and have deadlines, please if anybody can help me out with how i can set up chrome and selenium, that would be very much appreciated. i did see some solutions that required me to update the drivers, i did update the drivers. but not sure if they got updated to this. i am very new to behat and .yml coding. so please be patient and help me out.
thank you

Comment: Can you try to setup your capabilities in your yaml file not in json array but with normal fields?

Comment: I removed the capabilities and made a more and simple fresh yaml file, and it seemed to have worked out, my yaml file was probably too complicated. it was from a reference that made me come up with that file